# django file upload direct to buffer

Tags: python, django

I' d like to upload a file to a django view and pass it to a transform function which does everything else. The transform function `db_transform_and_save` expects a file-like object. My working solution so far is:

```
class UploadView(FormView):
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    form_class = MyUploadForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        db_transform_and_save(form.cleaned_data['my_upload'].read())
```

My questions are:

1. is there any way of data loss?
2. What would happen if the connection fails during upload? Would it mean for my `db_transform_and_save` function to run forever?
3. Ihat would happen if there are to many connections for the server to handle?
4. Would I need some sort of que - mechanism?

I am running this django app with a gunicorn, 4 workers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If your server crashes or the connection gets lost, yes, you'll loose the data - no way around that unless you micro-manage your file upload, transfer very small chunks and implement an acknowledgement-layer on your own - as long as you are not overly mission critical, this might be overkill...
2. The POSTed data will not arrive, you will recieve an empty document (which you should check in your `db_transform_and_save`!)
3. It'll slow down. If there are way to many, it'll slow down significantly (up to nearly no reaction). If you expect heavy data load, you should test your system with realistic upload sizes. In normal situations, everything should just run smoothly...
4. As longas your uploads do not interfere with each other, you need nothing else.